# Using alias inside a class instead of declaring a new class

Tags: c#, typedef, using

I have a complex event args class in a webservice

```
public partial class PROJECT.WCF.MyActionCompletedEventArgs 
{
...
};
```

Now I have a class that wraps this web service in some way

```
public class WebserviceCtrl
{
...
```

Now I want to add my own handler with the same event args already defined. So I want a `using` alias (like a `typedef` in C++) inside the class like this:

```
public class WebserviceCtrl
{
  using ActionCompletedEventArgs = PROJECT.WCF.MyActionCompletedEventArgs;
  ...
```

But I get a syntax error directly in front of the using statement. I can use this using statement directly in front of the class declaration (inside a namespace). It doesn't matter where I place this statement inside the class definition.

I know about the possibilities of declaring my own `ActionCompletedEventArgs` class, but in this case I have to provide specific constructors and forces me to write specific constructors that aren't "needed", if I just use an alias...
 So I don't want to declare my own class!

I already studied the C# using documentation, but I could find any information about this.

My question is, why can't I use using `classx = classy;` inside my class?

Comment: The error message you're getting is giving you the exact answer to your question, and in your question you even describe how to make it work.  There is nothing left to answer.

Comment: The problem is that I can't derive my own class. There are members in the event args class that are private and have a special getter that will throw. I can't create my own vent args class with the same member and same behaviour. Only using the exact same class and I wanted to prevent this.

Comment: Then use that exact same class.  You still don't have a question to answer.

Comment: My question is, why can't I use using classx = classy; inside my class? It isn't answered even if my question is down voted (and I don't understand this).

Comment: The error message you get with your code tells you exactly why.  So you already know the answer to that question.

Comment: What´s the matter on declaring an instance of your class via an alias instead of the name of that specific class? I can´t see what the purpose here is.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis: Yes! This makes sense to me. Redirecting one class to another would really make things complicated.

Comment: @xMRi I've posted this as an answer - although I don't know if it got you any closer to a solution

Comment: @C.Evenhuis: I marked it as an answer. I think I need to derive my own classes. In C++ I would have used a typedef. A using alias doesn't create a new class or name. It is just something like a shortcut.... that is what I had to understand. But OK. That's C#....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aliases only apply to the *current file* (or the *current namespace scope within the current file*), and they do not exist in the compiled output. Just like the other using statements that "include" a namespace.

There's no reason to place them elsewhere at all, it would just make code harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a generic class like:

```
public class WebserviceCtrl<T> where T : MyActionCompletedEventArgs
```

What you are trying to do isn't supported in the way you are trying to do it, but if you're trying to reference a variable class, generics are how that's accomplished in C#.